# Retrieving data using queries based on the value of checkboxes in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a spreadsheet for a company to track data on previous leads that were all in various stages of development. The goal is to have a sheet with a number of dropdown menus to select the type of lead and subtypes and then the stage of development for the lead using checkboxes. There are 9 total stages that a lead can be in. E.g. lead type A at stage 5. The sheet then retrieves all of the previous leads with lead type A and stage 5 and lists the data on them using queries.

This is simple enough for me, however the next feature request was to allow the spreadsheet to retrieve data with a combination of checkboxes checked. E.g. all leads of type A in stages 5, 6 and 7.  The sheet should then show all of these leads in the dashboard along with their values.

What I've tried so far (besides a lot of google searching) is to use a bunch of nested if statements (which is obviously awful coding), but this only confuses me and I'm sure there's a better solution. I'm just not sure how else to get all of the info I need without using a huge number of if-statements (I don't usually work with google sheets or excel). The lead type isn't even that important, I just want to know how I can work with the checkboxes to avoid having to write out 126 different combinations using if statements.

Comment: Edited, because the google sheets tag didn't show up before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Apps Script Solution

With data like this

[image]

To create a report like this:

[image]

That updates every time you change a checkbox, the easiest way IMO to do it, is with Apps Script.

Go to the script editor and paste in this function:

```js
function onEdit() {
  // Initialize variables
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  let reportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Report")
  
  // Clear previous report
  reportSheet.getRange("F2:H").clear()
  
  // Get criteria from check boxes
  let types = reportSheet.getRange("A1:B7").getValues()
  let stages = reportSheet.getRange("C1:D9").getValues()
  types = types.filter(type => type[1] == true).map(type => type[0])
  stages = stages.filter(stage => stage[1] == true).map(stage => stage[0])
 
  // Get data to filter and filter
  let dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
  let data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  data = data.filter(row => types.includes(row[1]) && stages.includes(row[2]))
  
  // Write report
  let rows = data.length
  let cols = data[0].length
  let outputRange = reportSheet.getRange(2, 6, rows, cols).setValues(data)
}
```

For this function to work you would need your data to be in the format above in a sheet called "Data" and the report would also need to be in the same format, in a sheet called "Report".

*You most likely will need to adapt the function for your specific use case, since you didn't attach an example sheet, I had to invent my own format.*

#### References

- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Sheets Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials)
- [Sheets Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)